# How to combine PHP array from user input with MySQL table for calculation (conceptually)?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, time-series

I have a website, where a user can enter a time series (date; series) into a text area. The data is sent to the server using the POST method.

I have a few tables with different time series already stored in the MySQL database. 
The user specified time series and those stored in the database should be combined for statistical calculations.

I store the user input into an array using explode and want to select the time series from the database using the date as the selector (`WHERE date = $datefromuserinput`).
I have two problems here:

- The date format for the array does not match the one in MySQL (ISO, o-m-d) after several transformations (e.g. `strtotime`).
- Also, the time series data type in MySQL is in DECIMAL (15,4) format, but the one in PHP is string (transformed to `float`).

Before trying to find solutions, I would like to know if my concept is right and best. Putting the user input into a MySQL table would make calculations faster (as I understand). However, several users can use the form simultaneously that would result in overwriting the entries in the new table in MySQL, right? Should I load the complete MySQL table into a PHP array (session necessary)?

I have read many solutions but could not find these answer. Any hint would be highly appreciated.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

//session_start();

//$datum = [];

if ($_POST['usersubmit']) {
if ($_POST['userinput1'] !=""){

        if ($_POST['separator'] != ""){
        if ($_POST['separator'] == comma){
        $separatorsign = ",";
        }
        elseif ($_POST['separator'] == semicolon){
        $separatorsign = ";";
        }
        else {
        $separatorsign = "\t";
        }
    }



$userinput1 = $_POST['userinput1'];


$zeilen= explode("\n", $userinput1);
$daten = array();
foreach($zeilen as $zeile) {
    list($datum, $zeitreihe) = explode($separatorsign, $zeile,2);
$datumkonv = strtotime($datum);


$daten[]['datum'] = date('o-m-d',$datumkonv);
$daten[]['zeitreihe'] = $zeitreihe;

}



$con = mysql_connect('localhost','username','pw');
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error($con));
}

mysql_select_db("dbname");

$sql = "SELECT series FROM mytimeseries1 WHERE date = $daten[0]['datum']"; //[0]     just     for trying working with the first row

$result = mysql_query($sql); 

$row = mysql_fetch_object($result);

echo "$row->series";//["series"].'<br>';

$row = floatval($row);

$ergebnis = $row + 22;
echo $ergebnis; // $row is 100.5000 but $ergebnis returns 100.5023 ??


mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($con);


echo "<pre>";

//print_r ($result);
 print_r ($row);
var_dump($row); 
var_dump($ergebnis);




}
}



?>

<table width="800">
 <tr>
  <td width="400">
<form action="test.php" method="post">
 <p><textarea style="overflow-y:scroll;resize:none;" name="userinput1"   id="userinput1" cols="28" rows="12"></textarea></p>


   <p>Separator<br>
   <input type="radio" name="separator" value="comma">Comma</p>
     <p><input type="radio" name="separator" value="tab">Tab</p>
 <p><input type="radio" name="separator" value="semicolon">Semicolon</p>
   </td>     
   <td width="400">
 <p>Date Format<br>
 <input type="radio" name="dateformat" value="yyyy-mm-dd">YYYY-MM-DD</p>
 <p><input type="radio" name="dateformat" value="yyyy-dd-mm">YYYY-DD-MM</p>
 <p><input type="radio" name="dateformat" value="dd-mm-yyyy">DD-MM-YYYY</p>
 <p><input type="radio" name="dateformat" value="mm-dd-yyyy">MM-DD-YYYY</p>
 <p><input type="radio" name="dateformat" value="ddmmyyyy">DD.MM.YYYY</p>


   <p><input type="submit" name="usersubmit" value="GO"></p>
</form>
   </td>
  </tr> 
 </table>

<?php
```

**EDIT:** After trying for hours I think that it makes more sense to upload the user input array into a temporary table in MySQL (date format is accepted etc). I had to change the foreach()-part in the code above to:

```
for($y = 0;$y < count($zeilen);$y++){
    list($datum, $zeitreihe) = explode($separatorsign, $zeilen[$y], 2);
    $daten[$y]['datum'] = $datum;
    $daten[$y]['zeitreihe'] = $zeitreihe;
    }
```

Comment: got the question , would you mind showing us what have you tried so far

Comment: Try, try and try again... use a decent profiler tool, write tests, or use `microtime` to measure which approach is the faster... we don't know what kind of setup you have, nor what your code looks like. Just _try_ stuff. If you read on site X that function _f_ was slower thand function _g_ 2 years ago, that doesn't mean that still holds true today... just see for yourself

Comment: @Satya: hope code helps. the radio field for dateformat is not in use so far.@Elias: I am not at the point to test with microtime because I am not able to have a working sample